# Prediction of intercept random effect in mgcv with a t2 smooth specification of a continuous predictor

Tags: random-effects-model, mgcv

I'm fitting gam models in `mgcv` with a "cr" spline applied to continuous regressor + an intercept random effect by group.

When the "cr" spline is specified with the `s` function, prediction of intercept random effect, are, as expected, centered (0 mean). However, if I specify the "cr" spline with `t2` function, predicted random effects are no more centered (part of the intercept is transfered to the random effects).

The following example illustrates the problem. I fitted the model $y_{ij}=f(x_i)+b_{j}+\epsilon_{ij}$ to simulated gaussian data with 10 groups and 15 observations per group, where $f=\exp$, using "cr" regression splines with 5 df specified with `s` and `t2`.

```
> library(mgcv)
> dt<-tibble(gp=as.factor(rep(1:10,each=15)),
+            x=rep(1:15,10))%>%
+   group_by(gp)%>%
+   mutate(re=rnorm(1))%>%
+   ungroup()%>%
+   mutate(y=5+exp(as.numeric(scale(x)))+re+rnorm(1))
> 
> m_s<-gam(y~s(x,bs="cr",k=5)+s(gp,bs="re"),data=dt,
+          method="REML")
> m_t2<-gam(y~t2(x,bs="cr",k=5)+s(gp,bs="re"),data=dt,
+           method="REML")
```

`m_s`and `m_t2` look similar, except in their intercepts.

```
> summary(m_s)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x, bs = "cr", k = 5) + s(gp, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   8.1391     0.3266   24.92   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
        edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(x)  3.998      4 46683  <2e-16 ***
s(gp) 8.999      9  9621  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.999   Deviance explained =  100%
-REML = -206.28  Scale est. = 0.0016624  n = 150
> summary(m_t2)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ t2(x, bs = "cr", k = 5) + s(gp, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 7.399190   0.003026    2445   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
        edf Ref.df     F p-value    
t2(x) 3.998      4 46681  <2e-16 ***
s(gp) 8.999     10  8660  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.999   Deviance explained =  100%
-REML = -205.4  Scale est. = 0.0016624  n = 150
>
```

Looking at the predicted random effects, `s` model re are centered, whereas `t2` model are not, with a constant difference between the two predictions equal to the difference in intercepts.

```
> mean(coefficients(m_s)[-(1:5)])
[1] 1.44329e-15
> mean(coefficients(m_t2)[-(1:5)])
[1] 0.739919
> coefficients(m_s)[-(2:5)]-coefficients(m_t2)[-(2:5)]
(Intercept)     s(gp).1     s(gp).2     s(gp).3     s(gp).4     s(gp).5     s(gp).6     s(gp).7     s(gp).8     s(gp).9    s(gp).10 
   0.739919   -0.739919   -0.739919   -0.739919   -0.739919   -0.739919   -0.739919   -0.739919   -0.739919   -0.739919   -0.739919 
>
```

Does anyone know why such a difference between the two formulations of the same model?